# MYSQL -connection to database unknown

Tags: mysql

I am using Struts and Hibernate for my web application. And also i have installed Glassbox to troubleshooting my java application. Backend database is MYSQL 5.1.

The problem is I can not able to get Glassbox's query stack. Instead i am getting error like

"connection to database unknown".

But if i connect my application with sql server database, query is shown.

What is the issue in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. Glassbox will not print query stack for MYSQL. 
So i migrate my mysql query to sql server. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

can you check the connection string and then verify whether the given database is there?

Comment: Application is working good. But the glassbox does not show the query.

Comment: There's a very good site that details all connections http://www.connectionstrings.com/
Also, this is a long shot, any chance that glassbox is being blocked by firewall???

Comment: Firewall does not block anything.

Comment: I fixed this. Glassbox will not print query stack for MYSQL. 
So i migrate my mysql query to sql server. Now it is working fine.